# Extracting values from json

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to extract the name and url from this Json.

Here's my Json and Javascript. This successfully loops through and extracts each object e.g. the "1977" portion. But I need to then extract the name and url and display them. Can anyone help? It's so simple I can barely believe I have to ask.

```
[{
    "1977": [{
        "name": "my name 1",
        "url": "myurl 1"
    }],
    "2104": [{
        "name": "my name 2",
        "url": "myurl 2"
    }]
}]

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); //a parses above json
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    console.log(obj[i]); //returns the object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the objects and pick only the attributes needed, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for (var year in obj[i]) {
        console.log("Current year is", year);
        console.log(obj[i][year][0].name);
        console.log(obj[i][year][0].url);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Current year is 1977
my name 1
myurl 1
Current year is 2104
my name 2
myurl 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
   console.log(obj[i][0].name); 
   console.log(obj[i][0].url); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to access the name.

```
obj[0]['1977'][0]['name']

obj[0]['1977'][0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<obj[i].length; j++) {

        console.log(obj[i][j][0].name);
        console.log(obj[i][j][0].url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply extract using dot operator

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var og = obj[i];
    Object.keys(og).forEach(function (key) {  //missed to loop through it
        console.log(og[key][0].name);
        console.log(og[key][0].url);
    });

}
```